# google_assistant_sdk connect timed out

Tags: java, sdk, assistant

code:

```
Response<OAuthCredentials> response = 
      oAuthClient.getAccessToken(code,authenticationConf.getClientId(),
      authenticationConf.getClientSecret(),
      authenticationConf.getCodeRedirectUri(),
      "authorization_code").execute();
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mautini.assistant.demo.exception.AuthenticationException: Error during authentication
    at com.mautini.assistant.demo.authentication.AuthenticationHelper.authenticate(AuthenticationHelper.java:75)
    at com.mautini.assistant.demo.GoogleAssistantClient.main(GoogleAssistantClient.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

---

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thanks Roshana Pitigala ! The problem is I can't get the object return from google assistant sdk ---> Response<OAuthCredentials>.